# aws lambda using .net core 2.0

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am trying to leverage the .net core 2.0 for AWS lambda and could not find any documentation for its support for same.

Has anyone tried lambda targetting .net core 2.0 or is it supported?

Comment: Yeah, I agree w/ @Garnaph.  I don't know why this downvoted, but I couldn't find any documentation on this shy of this question... Obviously the downvoters aren't using AWS, Lambdas, and .Net Core

Comment: FYI for anybody late to the party, it is [coming....](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/149)

Comment: As of 2018/01 this is now supported. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/01/aws-lambda-supports-c-sharp-dot-net-core-2-0/

Answer (score 6):

From the blog post [Updates for .NET Core Lambda Libraries](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/updates-for-net-core-lambda-libraries/) (8 May 2017):

> Lambda supports **.NET Core 1.0**. If you add a dependency to your .NET Core project that requires **.NET Core 1.1**, the .NET Core publishing tooling used by Amazon.Lambda.Tools will run without errors. However, when you run the function you’ll get errors because of the incompatibility. In version 1.5.0 of Amazon.Lambda.Tools we added validation on top of the .NET Core publishing tool to ensure that none of the dependencies for the project require a later runtime than Lambda supports.

Answer (score 3):

AWS Lambda now supports .net core 2.0:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/01/aws-lambda-supports-c-sharp-dot-net-core-2-0/